# OneToMany of abstract class in springboot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am running into the problem where when i want to get a many to one relation with an abstract class it gives the error it can't instantiate it, which is logical. However i want it to grab the instances of the parent classes, cd or dvd. In the database they are also linked to eachother. I have a table for collectables which have a relation to the cd and dvd table.
I have the following class structure:

```
public class Collection {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "collection", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Collectable> collectableList;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Collectable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "collection_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection collection;
}

@Entity
@Component("Cd")
public class Cd extends Collectable {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "dvd")
@Component(value = "DVD")
public class Dvd extends Collectable {}
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue? I still want to keep the abstract on the collectable since i dont want it to be instantiable.

I have tried looking in the documentation of JPA and various other spring boot or JPA related sources, but to no avail. I have also asked multiple AI in hopes of any ideas but nothing usefull came up.

Answer (score 1):

Even not liking that much, as it looks like an workaround rather than a solution to accomplish OOP principles, you can map those using `@DiscriminatorColumn`. Define a column (collectable_type) to differentiate between subclasses like Cd and Dvd. Each subclass is marked with `@DiscriminatorValue` to specify its value in the collectable_type column. This setup enables JPA to manage polymorphic config, allowing retrieval of both CDs and DVDs via the Collection entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "collectable")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "collectable_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Collectable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "collection_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection collection;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Cd")
public class Cd extends Collectable {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Dvd")
public class Dvd extends Collectable {}
```